# Secret Hitler: is asking another player to choose which card to discard "cheating?"

Tags: house-rules, secret-hitler

To signal one's allegiance to the Liberals as President, one could say to another player, "all my cards are Fascist and it matters not which one I discard! Tell me which card of the 3 to discard!"

Similarly, the Chancellor could hold out two cards to another play and say, "all my cards are Fascist; choose one to discard" and also pass the choice onto another player, again signaling trustworthiness.

Is this kind of move allowed (or *should it* be allowed)? Is it in any way "cheating?"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes it is cheating and called out in the rules.

[Rules](https://secrethitler.com/assets/Secret_Hitler_Rules.pdf)

> Verbal and nonverbal communication between the
>   President and Chancellor is forbidden. The
>   President and Chancellor MAY NOT pick Policies
>   to play at random, shuffle the tiles before 
>   discarding one, or do anything else clever to
>   avoid secretly and intentionally selecting a
>   Policy. Additionally, the President should hand
>   both Policies over at the same time, rather
>   than one at a time to gauge the Chancellor’s
>   reaction. Attempting to telegraph the contents
>   of your hand using randomness or any other
>   unusual selection procedure violates the spirit
>   of the game. Don’t do it.

Additionally

> Discarded Policy tiles should never be revealed
>   to the group. Players must rely on the word of
>   the President and Chancellor, who are free to
>   lie.

Simply put once the election is over the President and Chancellor should stop all communication and move to quickly enact a new policy by following the rules and this should be done in a timely manner as to not give any hidden meanings from the actions.

- President draws 3 policies
- President discards one and hands the other two over at the same time to the Chancellor
- Chancellor discards one of the policies and then enacts the other one.
- At this point and only this point can the President and or Chancellor make claims about what policies they had to chose from

As a side note one very important thing to remember is that no matter what side someone is on they are going to make a claim about having no choice if a fascist policy is enacted. Also a claim can easily be made that the Chancellor was given a choice when a fascist policy was enacted and it was just a fascist President trying to make a liberal Chancellor look bad. The key point here is that the claims of what cards each player had to chose from need to be taken with a large grain of salt as you can easily lie about them.